My fortran code gives error:" Missing actual argument "
I am trying to compile this fortran code but it gives error like below.  I wrote "this part give the error" next to the line  for the relevant parts to indicate where the error hapens.
I am trying to declare L and TMAX  and add
REAL :: L
L = (100) 
INTEGER :: TMAX
TMAX = 100 

but not satisfy.
I will be grateful if you have a suggestion to solve this issue.
error code:
main.f95:180:25: 180 | &F,TP,TN,TMAX,DT,P,L) | 1 Error: Missing actual argument for argument ‘l’ at (1) 
               main.f95:183:25: 183 | &F,TP,TN,TMAX,DT,P,L) | 1 Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘tmax’ at (1); passed REAL(4) to INTEGER(4)

dimension YO(400), TERSY(400)
REAL N,L
character*14 FILEOU
AREA(B,YY,Z)=(B+Z*YY)*YY
PERI(B,YY,Z)=B+2*YY*(1+Z**2)**0.5
WRITE(*,8)
8 format(/,19X,'PLEASE ENTER THE OUTPUT FILE NAME',//)
READ(*,8008)FILEOU
8008 FORMAT(A14)
OPEN(3,FILE=FILEOU)
READ(*,*)QWE
WRITE(*,*)'DOWNSTREAM BOUNDARY CONDITION:'
WRITE(*,*)'SPILLWAY (1), BOTTOM OUTLET (2)'
READ(*,*)ICHECK
IF(ICHECK.EQ.1)then
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER SPILLWAY HEIGHT, P(m)'
read(*,*)P
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER SPILLWAY CREST LENGTH, L(m)'
READ(*,*)L
ENDIF
IF(ICHECK.EQ.2) THEN
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER DISCHARGE COEFFICIENT'
READ(*,*)C
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER DIAMETER OF BOTTOM OUTLET(m)'
READ(*,*)D
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER THE NUMBER OF BOTTOM OUTLETS'
READ(*,*)NNN
ENDIF
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER STEADY - STATE DISCHARGE (m^3/s)'
READ(*,*)QQ
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER BOTTOM WIDTH(m)'
READ(*,*)BB
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER SIDE INCLINATION'
READ(*,*)ZZ
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER BED SLOPE'
READ(*,*)S0
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER MANNING ROUGHNESS'
READ(*,*)N
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER Dx(m)'
READ(*,*)DXX
WRITE(*,*)'CHOOSE THE SOLUTION TECHNIQUE:'
WRITE(*,*)'COMPLETE DYNAMIC WAVE(5)'
WRITE(*,*)'DIFFUSIVE WAVE(6)'
WRITE(*,*)'KINEMATIC WAVE(7)'
READ(*,*)IMETHOD
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER TIME INTERVAL Dt, (sec)'
READ(*,*)Dt
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER THE HYDROGRAPH PARAMETERS :'
WRITE(*,*)'Qo(m^3/S)'
READ(*,*)QQ0
WRITE(*,*)'Qp (m^3/s) AND Tp(sec)'
READ(*,*)QQP
READ(*,*)Tp
WRITE(*,*)'Qf(m^3/s) AND Tn (sec)'
READ(*,*)QQF
READ(*,*)Tn
WRITE(*,*)'Tmax(sec)'
READ(*,*)
TmaxYNN=0.01
99 ETOTAL=(QQ*N)/S0**.5
ECHECK=AREA(BB,YNN,ZZ)**(5./3.)/PERI(BB,YNN,ZZ)**(2./3.)
IF(ETOTAL.LT.ECHECK)GOTO 100
YNN=YNN+.01
GOTO 99
100 W=QQ/(3.132*BB**2.5)
IF(ZZ.EQ.0)THEN
YCOB=W**.672717*1.022785
ELSE IF(ZZ.EQ.5) THEN
YCOB=W**.602684*0.748173
ELSE IF(ZZ.EQ.1) THEN
YCOB=W**.574105*0.657397
ELSE IF(ZZ.EQ.1.5) THEN
YCOB=W**.564345*0.625201
ELSE IF(ZZ.EQ.2) THEN
YCOB=W**.552851*0.584043
ELSE IF(ZZ.EQ.2.5) THEN
YCOB=W**.545379*0.552333
ELSE IF(ZZ.EQ.3) THEN
YCOB=W**.537298*0.523298
ELSE IF(ZZ.EQ.4) THEN
YCOB=W**.524667*0.487638
END IF
YC=YCOB*BB
IF(YNN.GT.YC)THEN
WRITE(3,551)
551 FORMAT('HYDRAULIC PARAMETERS RESULT IN MILD SLOPE' ,/)
ELSE
WRITE(3,552)
552 FORMAT('THIS PROGRAM IS NOT VALID FOR STEEP SLOPE CASE' ,/)
GO TO 553
ENDIF
IF(ICHECK.EQ.1) THEN
H0=0.1
98 X=P/H0
IF(X.GE.2.8)THEN
CO=2.175
ELSE
C0=.018*X**7-.218*X**6+1.084*X**5-2.872*X**4+4.37*X**3-3.847*X**&
&2+1.889*X+1.72
ENDIF
QCHECK=C0*L*H0**1.5
IF(QQ.LT.QCHECK) GOTO 101
H0=H0+.05
GOTO 98
101 YMAX = P+H0
ELSE
YMAX=0.0826*QQ**2/(NNN**2*C**2*D**4)
ENDIF
KZ=ZZ
WRITE(3,15)QQ,YMAX,YNN,BB,KZ,S0,N,DXX,YC
15 FORMAT(10X,'Q(m3/s =',F6.1,/,10x,'Ymax(m)=',F6.3,/,10X,'Yn(&
&m)=',F6.3,/,/,10X,'B(m)=',f6.1,/,10x,'Z=1V:',I1,'H',/,10X,'So&
&=',F6.5,/,10X,'n=',F6.3,/,10X,'DX(m)=',F6.3,/,10X,'Yc(m)=&
&',F6.3,///)
WRITE(3,50)
50 FORMAT(1X,'I',5X,'Z',6X,'Y',5X,'A',5X,'P',5X,'R',6X,'U',7X,'Sf',6X&
&,'H',7X,'HE',5X,'LENGTH',/,6X,'(m)'4X,'(m)',2X'(m2)',3X,'(m)',3X&
&,'(m)',3X,'(m/s)',11X,'(m)',5X,'(m)',/,78('At'),/)
T=0.
Z1=0.
Y1=Ymax
I=1
A1=AREA(BB,Y1,ZZ)
P1=PERI(BB,Y1,ZZ)
R1=A1/P1
U1=QQ/A1
S1=(U1*N/R1**(2./3.))**2
H1=Z1+Y1+U1**2/19.625201
WRITE(3,51)I,Z1,Y1,A1,P1,R1,U1,S1,H1
51 FORMAT(1X,I3,1X,F6.3,1X,F6.3,1X,2(F7.1,1X),2(F6.3,1X),F7.6,1X,F6.3&
&,1X,F6.2,3X,F7.1)
30 I=I+1
T=T+DXX
Z2=Z1+S0*DXX
Y2=0.
10 Y2=Y2+0.01
A2=AREA(BB,Y2,ZZ)
P2=PERI(BB,Y2,ZZ)
R2=A2/P2
U2=QQ/A2
S2=(U2*N/R2**(2./3.))**2
H2=Z2+Y2+U2**2/19.62
H22=H1+.4*DXX*(S1+S2)
HE=H2-H22
HHE=HE*100
IF(ABS(HE).LT.0.0074) GOTO 20
GOTO 10
20 FRU2 = U2/(9.81*Y2)**.5
DELY=HE/(1-FRU2**2+(3*S2*DXX)/(2*R2))
Y2=Y2-DELY
WRITE(3,51)I,Z2,Y2,A2,P2,R2,U2,S2,H2,HHE,T
IF(Y2.LE.YNN) GOTO 40
WRITE(*,*)I,Y2
TERSY(I)=Y2
Y1=Y2
A1=A2
P1=P2
R1=R2
U1=U2
S1=S2
Z1=Z2
H1=H2
S1=S2
GOTO 30
40 WRITE(3,75) T
75 FORMAT(//,10X,'TOTAL LENGTH IS',F7.1,'m',//)
YO(1) = YNN
YO(1) =YMAX
WRITE(*,*)T,I
DO 597 K =2,I-1
YO(K)=TERSY(I-K+1)
597 CONTINUE
WRITE(*,9)
9 FORMAT(//,15('!'),3X,'PLEASE WAIT COMPUTATION CONTUNIES',3X,15('!'&
&))
IF(IMETHOD.EQ.5)CALL COMPW(QQ,BB,S0,N,DXX,YNN,I,ZZ,YO,ICHECK,D,&
&C,NNN,QQ0,QQP,QQF,TP,TN,TMAX,DT,P,L)
IF(IMETHOD.EQ.6)&
&CALL DIFFW(QQ,BB,S0,N,DXX,YNN,I,ZZ,YO,QQP,QQ&
&F,TP,TN,TMAX,DT,P,L)       !***********THIS PART GIVES ERROR**************
IF(IMETHOD.EQ.7)&
&CALL KINEW(QQ,BB,S0,N,DXX,YNN,I,ZZ,YO,QQ0,QQP,QQ&
&F,TP,TN,TMAX,DT,P,L)       !**********THIS PART GIVES ERROR**************
553 STOP 
END

SUBROUTINE &
&DIFFW(QQ,BB,S0,N,DXX,YNN,I,ZZ,YO,QQ0,QQP,QQF,TP,TN,TMAX&
&,DT,P,L)
REAL N,L
DIMENSION DX(400),UO(400),YO(400),Y(400),U(400),Q(400),QO(400)
AREA(B,YY,Z)=(B+Z*YY)*YY
PERI(B,YY,Z)=B+2*YY*(1+Z**2)**.5
WRITE(3,*) 'THIS PRINT OUT IS CALCULATED FROM DIFFUSIVE WAVE'
QIN=QQ
WID=BB
S=S0
CON=N
DL=DXX
DX(1)=0
DO 15 K=1,I
DX(K+1)=DX(K)+DL
15 CONTINUE
WRITE(3,990)
990 FORMAT (2X,'TIME=0',/)
WRITE(3,1010) QIN
1010 FORMAT (2X,'INITIAL DISCHARGE=',F9.4,/)
WRITE(3,1020)
1020 FORMAT (2X,'LENGTH ',3X,'DEPTH '/)
WRITE(3,1030) (DX(K),YO(K),K=1,I)
1030 FORMAT (2X,F12.4,3X,F10.4)
DO 17 K=1,17
QO(K)=QIN
17 CONTINUE
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER THE PRINT OUT TIME INTERVAL, (sec)'
READ(*,*)J
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER CHEZY COEFFICIENT'
READ(*,*)CHEZ
DO 20 LTIME=1,INT(TMAX)
WRITE(*,*)LTIME
! EQUATIONS OF FLOOD HYDROGRAPH
DIS=QQ0+(QQP-QQO)/TP*LTIME
IF(LTIME.GT.TP) DIS=QQP-(QQP-QQF)/(TN-TP)*(LTIME-TP)
IF(LTIME.GT.TN) DIS=QQF
! DETERMINATION OF VELOCITIES AND WATER DEPTHS AT TIME LEVEL N
Y(1)=0.01
115 ETOTAL=(DIS*CON)/S**.5
ECHECK=(AREA(WID,Y(1),ZZ))**(5./3.)/(PERI(WID,Y(1),ZZ))**(2./3.)
IF(ETOTAL.LT.ECHECK) GOTO 110
Y(1) = Y(1)+.01
GOTO 115
110 Q(1)=DIS
DX(1)=0
DO 30 K=2,I-2
! DEFINE THE CHEZY COEFFICIENT
DX(K+1)=DX(K)+DL
A1=(1/YO(K)+1/2./YO(K))
C=CHEZ*(YO(K)*(S-((YO(K+1)-YO(K))/(DL))))**.5*A1*YO(K)
A2=2*WID*(S-((YO(K+1)-YO(K))/DL))
T=CHEZ*(YO(K)*(S-((YO(K+1)-YO(K))/(DL))))**.5*YO(K)*WID
D=T/A2
Y1=D*(YO(K+2)-2*YO(K+1)+YO(K))/DL**2.
Y2=C*(YO(K+1)-YO(K))/DL
Y(K)=YO(K)+DT*(Y1-Y2)
U(K)=DIS/WID/Y(K)
30 CONTINUE
DO 40 K=I-1,I
IF(K.EQ.I-1) DX(K+1)=DX(K)+DL
A1=(1/YO(K)+1/2./YO(K))
C=CHEZ*(YO(K)*(S-((YO(K)-YO(K-1))/(DL))))**.5*A1*YO(K)
A2=2*WID*(S-((YO(K)-YO(K-1))/DL))
T=CHEZ*(YO(K)*(S-((YO(K)-YO(K-1))/(DL))))**.5*YO(K)*WID
D=T/A2
Y1=D*(YO(K)-2*YO(K-1)+YO(K-2))/DL**2.
Y2=C*(YO(K)-YO(K-1))/DL
40 CONTINUE
Y(K)=YO(K)+DT/DL*(Y1+Y2)
IF(J.EQ.LTIME) THEN
J=J+1
WRITE(3,111)LTIME
111 FORMAT(//,2x,'tıme=',I6,/)
write(3,1101) DIS
1101 FORMAT (2X,'DISCHARGE=',F10.4,/)
write(3,105)
105 format(2X,'LENGTH',3X,'DEPTH ',/)
WRITE(3,106)(DX(K),Y(K),K=1,I)
106 FORMAT (2X,F12.4,3X,F10.4)
ENDIF
! REPLACING
DO 50 K=1,I
YO(K)=Y(K)
50 continue
20 continue
return
END

SUBROUTINE KINEW(QQ,BB,SO,N,DXX,YNN,I,ZZ,YO,QQ0,QQP,QQF,TP,TN,&
&TMAX&
&,DT,P,L)
REAL N,L
real :: y(400)
INTEGER :: TMAX ! Declare TMAX as an integer
DIMENSION DX(400),AO(400),YO(400),A(400),DIS(400),U(I)
AREA(B,YY,Z)=(B+Z*YY)*YY
PERI(B,YY,Z)=B+2*YY*(1+Z**2)**.5
WRITE(3,*)'THIS PRINT OUT IS CALCULATED FROM KINEMATIC WAVE'
QIN=QQ
WID=120.
S=S0
CON=N
DL=DXX
COEF=5./3
ALPHA=S**0.5/(CON*WID**(2./3))
DX(1)=0.
DO 15 K=1,I-1
DX(K+1)=DX(K)+DL
15 CONTINUE
! DETERMINATION OF AREAS AT STEADY STATE FLOW
DO 20 K=1,I
AO(K)=AREA(WID,YO(K),ZZ)
20 CONTINUE
WRITE(3,79)
79 FORMAT(2X,'TIME = 0',/)
WRITE(3,801) QIN
801 FORMAT (2X,'INITIAL DISCHARGE=',F9.4,/)
WRITE(3,802)
802 FORMAT (5X,'LENGTH ',6X,' DPETH ',6X,'AREA'/)
WRITE(3,803)(DX(K),YO(K),AO(K),K=1,I)
803 FORMAT (2X,F12.4,3X,F10.4,3X,F10.4)
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER THE PRINT OUT TIME INTERVAL, (sec)'
READ(*,*)J
DO 30 LTIME=1,TMAX
WRITE(*,*)LTIME
! EQUATIONS OF FLOOD HYDROGRAPH
Q=QQ0+(QQP-QQ0)/TP*LTIME
IF(LTIME.GT.TP) Q=QQP-(QQP-QQF)/(TN-TP)*(LTIME-TP)
IF(LTIME.GT.TN) Q=QQF
! DETERMINATION OF AREAS AND WATER DEPTHS AT TIME LEVEL N
Y(1)=0.01
121 ETOTAL=(Q*CON)/S**.5
ECHECK=(AREA(WID,Y(1),ZZ))**(5./3.)/(PERI(WID,Y(1),ZZ))**(2./3.)
IF(ETOTAL.LT.ECHECK) GOTO 122
Y(1)=Y(1)+.01
GOTO 121
122 A(1)=AREA(WID,Y(1),ZZ)
DX(1)=0
DO 40 K=2,I-1
DX(K+1)=DX(K)+DL
Y1=(AO(K+1)-AO(K-1))/(2.*DL)
Y2=ALPHA*DT*COEF*AO(K)**(COEF-1)
A(K)=AO(K)-Y2*Y1
40 CONTINUE
DO 80 K=I,I
Y1=(AO(K)-AO(K-1))/DL
Y2=ALPHA*DT*COEF*AO(K)**(COEF-1)
A(K)=AO(K)+Y2*Y1
80 CONTINUE
DO 50 K=2,I
DIS(K)=ALPHA*A(K)**COEF
Y(K)=A(K)/WID
50 CONTINUE
IF(J.EQ.LTIME) THEN
J=J+J
WRITE(3,151)LTIME
151 FORMAT(//,2X,'TIME=',I6,/)
WRITE(3,157) Q
157 FORMAT (2X,'DISCHARGE=',F10.4,/)
WRITE(3,205)
205 FORMAT (5X,'LENGTH ',6X' DEPTH ',6X,'AREA ',/)
WRITE(3,206) (DX(K),Y(K),A(K),K=1,I)
206 FORMAT (2X,F12.4,3X,F10.4,3X,F10.4)
ENDIF
! REPLACING
DO 60 K=1,1
YO(K)=Y(K)
AO(K)=A(K)
60 CONTINUE
30 CONTINUE
RETURN
END

SUBROUTINE &
&COMPW(QQ,BB,S0,N,DXX,YNN,I,ZZ,YO,ICHECK,D,C,NNN,QQ0,QQP&
&,QQF,TP,TN,TMAX,DT,P,L)
REAL N,L
DIMENSION DX(400),UO(400),YO(400),Y(400),U(400)
AREA(B,YY,Z)=(B+Z*YY)*YY
PERI(B,YY,Z)=B+2*YY*(1+Z**2)**.5
WRITE(3,*)'RESULTS OF COMPLETE DYNAMIC WAVE'
QIN=QQ
WID=BB
S=S0
CON=N
DL=DXX
DX(1)=0
DO 15 K=1,I
UO(K)=QIN/AREA(WID,YO(K),ZZ)
DX(K+1)=DX(K)+DL

15 CONTINUE
WRITE(3,199)
199 FORMAT (2X,'TIME=0',/)
WRITE(3,101) QIN
101 FORMAT (2X, 'INITIAL DISCHARGE=',F9.4,/)
WRITE(3,102)
102 FORMAT (2X, 'LENGTH',3X,'DEPTH ',3X,'VELOCITY',/)
WRITE(3,103) (DX(K),YO(K),UO(K),K=1,I)
103 FORMAT (2X,F12.4,3X,F10.4,3X,F10.4)
WRITE(*,*)'ENTER THE PRINT OUT TIME INTERVAL, (sec)'
READ(*,*)J
DO 20 LTIME=1,INT(TMAX)
WRITE(*,*)LTIME
! EQUATIONS OF FLOOD HYDROGRAPH
DIS=QQ0+(QQP-QQ0)/TP*LTIME
IF(LTIME.GT.TP)DIS=QQP-(QQP-QQF)/(TN-TP)*(LTIME-TP)
IF(LTIME.GT.TN) DIS=QQF
! DETERMINATION OF VELOCTIES AND WATER DEPTHS AT TIME LEVEL NNN
Q=DIS
Y(1)=0.01
121 ETOTAL=(Q*CON)/S**.5
ECHECK=(AREA(WID,Y(1),ZZ))**(5./3.)/(PERI(WID,Y(1),ZZ))**(2./3.)
IF(ETOTAL.LT.ECHECK) GOTO 122
Y(1) = Y(1)+.01
GOTO 121
122 U(1)=Q/AREA(WID,Y(1),ZZ)
DX(1)=0
DO 30 K=2,I-1

DX(K+1)=DX(K)+DL
Y1=UO(K)*(YO(K-1)-YO(K+1))
Y2=YO(K)*(UO(K-1)-UO(K+1))
Y(K)=YO(K)+DT/2./DL*(Y1+Y2)
GAM=Y(K)**(4./3)/9.81/DT/CON**2
BET1=UO(K+1)-UO(K-1)
BET2=9.81*DT/2./DL*(YO(K+1)-YO(K-1))
BET=GAM*(UO(K)*DT/2./DL*BET1+BET2-9.81*DT*S-UO(K))
U(K)=(-GAM+(GAM**2.-4*BET)**0.5)/2.
30 CONTINUE
DO 40 K=I,I
Y1=YO(K)*(UO(K-1)-UO(K))
Y2=UO(K)*(YO(K-1)-YO(K))
Y(K)=YO(K)+DT/DL*(Y1+Y2)
IF(ICHECK.EQ.1) THEN
H00=Y(K)-P
X=P/H00
IF(X.GE.2.8) THEN
C0=2.175
ELSE
C0=.018*X**7-.218*X**6+1.084*X**5-2.872*X**4+4.37*X**3-3.847*X**&
&2+1.889*X+1.72
ENDIF
QDW=C0*L*H00**1.5
ELSE
QDW=C*NNN*3.14*D**2/4*(19.62*Y(K))**.5
ENDIF
U(K) =QDW/AREA(WID,Y(K),ZZ)
40 CONTINUE
IF(J.EQ.LTIME)THEN
J=J+1800
WRITE(3,111)LTIME
111 FORMAT (//,2X,'TIME=',I6,/)
WRITE(3,110) Q
110 FORMAT (2X,'DISCHARGE=',F10.4,/)
WRITE(3,105)
105 FORMAT (2X,'LENGTH',3X,'DEPTH',3X,'VELOCTIY',/)
WRITE(3,106)(DX(K),Y(K),U(K),K=1,I)
106 FORMAT (2X,F12.4,3X,F10.4,3X,F10.4)
ENDIF
! REPLACING
DO 50 K=1,I
YO(K)=Y(K)
UO(K)=U(K)
50 CONTINUE
20 CONTINUE
RETURN
END


Well the error message is about as clear as it can be, you haven't provided an actual argument for a corresponding dummy argument. Unfortunately the code as currently presented is very difficult to read, if you improve that someone might look to work out exactly where.

I wrote !THIS PART GIVER ERROR**** next to the line. Also I tried to add REAL :: L
L = (100) and INTEGER :: TMAX
TMAX = 100 but not satisfy.

Welcome. The code is really, really, hard to read. It helps a lot to add some indentation, that means spaces before nested statements. Also, use some empty lines to separate some logical blocks.

The error message is clear. It is really important to learn to understand the messages that the compiler gives you. A missing argument means that when you do CALL KINEW(..., you entered too few arguments. Check the arguments one by one. It helps a lot if you can have subroutines that do not need so many arguments. It is very hard to call subroutines with so many arguments correctly.

Also, you definitely do need to use IMPLICIT NONE. It is really very important. I cannot overstress the importance. It seems that the call to KINEW has the right number of arguments, that is 18, despite the very(!) confusingly split QQF argument. The error is in CALL DIFFW where you have 17 arguments instead of 18. Perhaps someone can tell you more but without the declarations it is impossible for me to guess which one.

In that case you have to accept that the code is wrong, it probably never worked properly, and if it ran with some compiler it probably gave incorrect answers because it is buggy and it is not worth converting it as is. Take the equations the code is supposed to solve and implement them in whichever progamming language you want. It is not worth following this code. Just follow the math.

I will do thank you

I had to roll back your edit. The existing answer would have made no sense.

I had to roll back your edit again. You are removing code that is important to the problem and even referenced in the existing answer - namely the subroutine KINEW.

If there is a confidentiality issue with the code, e.g. you didn’t have the right to post it, then the only solution is to suppress the question.

Apart being unreadable, your code is illegal Fortran, and your compiler rightfully detects the violations of the standard. Probably this code was compiling correctly in some distant past, because the compilers were generally more permissive.
First error:
main.f95:180:25: 180 | &F,TP,TN,TMAX,DT,P,L) | 1 Error: Missing actual argument for argument ‘l’ at (1) 
Your call to DIFFW() has only 17 arguments while the procedure declaration has 18. The dummy argument L is missing in call. However it seems that L is not used at all in the DIFFW() procedure, and that's probably why the call is omitting it. It's illegal code but it used to work...
You can make it working again either by

adding a fake 18th integer argument to the call
or requiring the compiler to NOT check the arguments; this is the option -fallow-argument-mismatch with gfortran, or -nogen-interfaces with Intel Fortran

Second error:
main.f95:183:25: 183 | &F,TP,TN,TMAX,DT,P,L) | 1 Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘tmax’ at (1); passed REAL(4) to INTEGER(4)
This one is more annoying. If you require the compiler to not check the argument as above, the error will disappear (it will just be a warning). However it has NO chance to work properly, as TMAX is effectively used in the procedure KINEW().
A solution here is to remove the declaration INTEGER :: TMAX ! Declare TMAX as an integer from KINEW(): TMAX will then be implicitly consider a REAL by the compiler. Then you will the warning:
  311 | DO 30 LTIME=1,TMAX
      |              1
Warning: Deleted feature: End expression in DO loop at (1) must be integer

It will be will work, though. But it will be better to write DO 30 LTIME=1,NINT(TMAX) instead.
Note: Allowing argument mismatch, and relying on legacy implicit typing (implicit noneis recommended in all codes nowadays) is generally a bad idea when writing new code.

The OP mentioned on the comments that it is not their code but a code they are trying to translate to a different language. Hence my recommendation to abandon the code there.
